# NullPointer while using Zebra Library in yet existing project

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Actually i'm trying to implement zebra EMDK library to my yet existing project.
I've followed step by step the following [guide](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/5-0/tutorial/tutdatacaptureprofilePt2/) and in a new project all worked perfectly but when i've tryed to use the library in my project i've got the following error:

```
2019-03-13 15:24:55.720 4671-4678/it.gabtamagnini.realco E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2019-03-13 15:25:01.239 4671-4671/it.gabtamagnini.realco E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.gabtamagnini.realco, PID: 4671
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.gabtamagnini.realco/it.gabtamagnini.realco.InventarioActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at it.gabtamagnini.realco.InventarioActivity.handleDecodeData(InventarioActivity.java:1160)
        at it.gabtamagnini.realco.InventarioActivity.onCreate(InventarioActivity.java:129)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Code where i get the null pointer:

```
  private void handleDecodeData(Intent i) {
        //Check the intent action is for us
        if (i.getAction().contentEquals("com.symbol.emdksample.RECVR")) {
            //Get the source of the data
            String source = i.getStringExtra("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.source");

            //Check if the data has come from the Barcode scanner
            if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("scanner")) {
                //Get the data from the intent
                String data = i.getStringExtra("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string");

                //Check that we have received data
                if(data != null && data.length() > 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(InventarioActivity.this,data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that tutorial is quite old - Data Capture Profiles were recently deprecated.  If you are trying this on a newer device then I suspect the com.motorolasolutions... Intents have been removed as the string extra has been 'com.symbol.datawedge.data_string for quite some time.  I suggest reading https://developer.zebra.com/community/home/blog/2018/06/03/moving-from-the-emdk-data-capture-profile-to-datawedge which explains what has happened to the Data Capture profile but if you are looking for a known working sample then http://www.darryncampbell.co.uk/2017/12/13/tutorial-scan-with-datawedge-intent-output-on-zebra-devices/ should be a good starting point.

For clarity, I work for Zebra

Comment: So in simple word EMDK is deprecated? As devices i have here the TC20, TC200J and the MC330M. Is there anyway to use Profile configuration in DataWedge from EMDK to set up the barcodes that the scanner should read?

Comment: Actually it was working for a while but after some other test's that intent broadcast just stopped to work.

Comment: Hi, no, sorry for the confusion but the EMDK is NOT deprecated, only that aspect of the EMDK which allows for the configuration of DataWedge.  You would typically use EITHER EMDK or DataWedge to control the scanner and receive barcode data into your application and if you are using DataWedge, you are able to configure it using standard Android Intents, i.e. no need to use the EMDK.